# mysql_fetch_array fetch date fetch each element twice

Tags: php, mysql

i hope to iterate the elements fetched from datebase
But the result looks very unexpected .
 I found the code below print the `$value` and `echo "<td id=".$key.$tag.">".$value."</td>";`twice. Is there anything i misunderstood?

```
   function selectTable($table){
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM ".$table ;
         $result=mysql_query($sql)
                          or die(mysql_error());
        return $result;
  }

  $table = 'battery_con';
  $result = selectTable($table);
  unset($table);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        ......
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                  print $value; 
                  echo "<td id=".$key.$tag.">".$value."</td>";
                }       
        .....
    }
```

Comment: off topic, but just to warn you: the `mysql_xxx()` functions in PHP are deprecated. You should consider using a more modern library such as PDO for your DB code.

Comment: @Spudley I know it ,but still appreciate for your ideas

Comment: @Akam query updated. Thanks

Comment: @Anigel query updated Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) which by default returns an array with two elements per column (this is what the second (optional) paramter means: `result_type = MYSQL_BOTH`).

One is indexed with an integer representing the column index, one is indexed with the column name.

That's why you get two entries in your list.  You would set the second parameter to `MYSQL_ASSOC` to get just one value per column.

Answer (score 3):

Please use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` place of `mysql_fetch_array()`
I hope it will help

Comment: @sonusindhhu can you explain why?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array return two index one is integer like and second is field name

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Andreas's answer by default `mysql_fetch_array` gives both associative and numeric indexes, if you don't want this you can limit it with the second parameter in your while loop:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM); // numeric keys only
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC); // associative keys only
```

As previously mentioned by @sonusindhu you can also use `mysql_fetch_row` to only get numeric keys, or `mysql_fetch_assoc` to only get associative keys.

Update

The mysql_xxx() functions being deprecated you should consider using the mysqli_xxx() functions instead.

See the example 1 of the php manual for more details:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php